# How to parse only part of a string-value from an element using Nokogiri? RUBY, Mechanize

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

How do I extract  numbers off a string ?
if xpath is 'td[5]p/@title'

**HTML :**

```
<td valign="top" align="center">
  <p title="6 en su sucursal" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom:0px; cursor:hand">   
   <b>10</b>
  </p>
</td>
```

I need to extract from the title attribute string-value "6 en su sucusal" only number 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give some HTML inside `html`, you'd do something like this:

```
doc     = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
numbers = doc.xpath('//p[@title]').collect { |p| p[:title].gsub(/[^\d]/, '') }
```

Then you'll have the numbers in the `numbers` array. You'll have to adjust the XPath and regular expression to match your real data of course but the basic technique should be clear.

A bit of time with the [Nokogiri documentation and tutorials](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials) might be fruitful.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Nokogiri tutorials are a bit hard to follow for a person who is just starting. But I am still trying to go thru them and get the logic out of there

Comment: @ingalcala: I hear you but the tutorials were all I had :) There's always `{ |x| puts x.class.inspect }` tricks and trying to read the class documentation.

Comment: haha I tried your code and instead of returning only the title number it returns all the numbers within the Paragraph tag

Comment: @ingalcala: Really? `doc.xpath('//p[@title]').collect { |p| p[:title].gsub(/[^\d]/, '') }` should give you the `title` attributes with all the non-numeric stuff removed.